# Security Token Service (STS) Over HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, wcf, token

I've created a new WCF Security Token Service in visual studio which runs fine over http.
I'm trying to configure it now to run over https. I've changed the directory secruity in IIS to require SSL.

As expected when I browse to the service via http I now receive the message "The page must be viewed over a secure channel". However, when I browse to the service via https I receive an error saying "Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WS2007HttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]."

I'm assuming there must be a configuration in the web.config file which I've overlooked but I'm not quite sure what it is. Any help in this matter would be great.

My web.config file is as per below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="IssuerName" value="ActiveSTS"/>
    <add key="SigningCertificateName" value="CN=STSTestCert"/>
    <add key="EncryptingCertificateName" value="CN=DefaultApplicationCertificate"/>
  </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings />

  <location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
          <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL = "true"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustServiceContract" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="IWSTrust13" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" contract="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrust13SyncContract"  bindingConfiguration="ws2007HttpBindingConfiguration"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/DemoSTS/Service.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <ws2007HttpBinding>
        <binding name="ws2007HttpBindingConfiguration">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007HttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add additional https base address.

If you are host over IIS, you have to configure SSL and to assign appropriate certificate for https channel.